# Cin and Cout quiz unable to complete

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I'm trying to make a basic quiz with a function using `cout` and `cin`, and I am stuck here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char askQuestion (int questionNumber, char* question, char* optionA, char* optionB, char* optionC) {
    char answer;
    cout << questionNumber << ".)" << question << "\n";
    cout << optionA << "\n";
    cout << optionB << "\n";
    cout << optionC << "\n";
    cin >> answer;
    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    char answer1;
    char answer2;
    char questionNumber;

    questionNumber = 1;
    answer1 = askQuestion(questionNumber, "Who is the Big Red Dog?", "A.)Milo", "B.)Clifford", "C.)Jack");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide the code, not the screenshot.

Comment: Pro-tip: C++ is not HTML and posting C++ code as an HTML snippet is not helpful.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: `char *` ===> `const char *` (or better [`std::string`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_string_handling)).

Comment: What is your problem? What part of the solution are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to output an answer?...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char askQuestion(int questionNumber, char* question, char* optionA, char* optionB, char* optionC) {
char answer{};
cout << questionNumber << ".)" << question << "\n";
cout << optionA << "\n";
cout << optionB << "\n";
cout << optionC << "\n";
cin >> answer;
return answer;
}
int main()
{
char answer1;
char answer2;
char questionNumber;

questionNumber = 1;
answer1 = askQuestion(questionNumber, "Who is the Big Red Dog?", "A.)Milo", "B.)Clifford", "C.)Jack");

(answer1 == 'B') ? cout << "CORRECT!!!" : cout << "INCORRECT!!!";
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```